# how can I use jquery with yii2

Tags: php, jquery, yii2

I am new in Yii framework (version 2.0) and I want to add some jQuery code to my page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div').click(function(){
        $(this).hide()
    });
});
```

This code will hide the div when I click on it, can I declare `<script>` in the view?

And how can I write this code in jQuery?

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-client-scripts.html

Comment: This shows totally NO effort, RTFM!

Answer (score 15):

First suggest you to change `($this)` to `$(this)` & try something like this.

```
$script = <<< JS
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div').click(function(){
        $(this).hide()
    });
}); 
JS;
$this->registerJs($script, View::POS_END);
```

You also can use `View::POS_HEAD`, `View::POS_BEGIN` & `View::POS_READY` instead of `View::POS_END`.

- [Reference](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/665/overcoming-removal-of-client-helpers-e-g-ajaxlink-and-clientscript-in-yii-2-0/)

Comment: in view write the following :

Comment: it worked <?php  $this->registerJs("
$('div').click(function() {
$(this).hide();
});           
 "); ?>

Answer (score 4):

> Try this , I hope this will help You

```
<?php

$this->registerJs(' 
    $(document).ready(function(){
         $(\'.classname\').hide();
});', \yii\web\View::POS_READY);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Yii2 jQuery and other script files by default comes at the end of the page right before html closing tag. This is good for faster page loading.

So if you write jQuery code in the middle of your page there will be `$ not defined` error. To solve that you should write jQuery code inside `window.onload` event:

```
window.onload=function(){
                        //your jQuery code here
                    };
```

Comment: Looks like a dirty solution. Why you should write it before `jQuery`? You should it include after. Yii2 provides solutions for that using `registerJs` and asset bundles dependencies.

Comment: you are right, we should include after. But in dev mode sometimes it's more convenient to write jQuery code right below the testing block of code